# I can't call a function in js file at html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a file, index.php with a tag

```
<a onclick="listenFilter()" ></a>
```

and a javascript named test.js linked to my index.php with the function name **listenFilter()**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
function listenFilter() {
    alert('a');
    return false;
}
});
```

It fails, and my browser says

> ReferenceError: listenFilter is not defined

But when I change the script to

```
function listenFilter() {
        alert('a');
        return false;
    }
```

It works.

What's different between those two situations?

Comment: It is because you click the link before document is ready and your code is written inside ready handler.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal for clarification only. How or when will the document be ready

Comment: @Pekka after all elements in document is read.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal the page has been loaded the document is ready. there for the anchor tag has been ready?right?why didnt the function inside the document ready get fired?Im just a bit confused now

Comment: if you click on after document is ready that would work fine.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal that was my first question for clarification. How would you determine if the document is ready?When the page is loaded?If that is the case then when the anchor tag is shown it means the document is ready because the anchor tag is loaded meaning the function should fire. Im sorry am a bit confuse here big time

Comment: There may be a lot of images too, don't? they all should be ready not just only anchor tag to ready. This is what document ready says.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal ok now its a bit clear i was just referring to only the anchor tag and no other elements present in the page. Thank you for the clarification

Comment: @Pekka You're welcome!

Comment: @BhojendraNepal sadly doesn't know what he's talking about. He's misleading you to believe it somehow has something to do with declaration order and not scope, when it is really all about scope. Sure, the document has to be ready, but that just means the document has loaded into the browser. It is because the `onclick` handler cannot access that function because it is not in scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **not** because the function is defined after the document is loaded. It is because of the scope it is defined in. Script tags in JavaScript automatically bind all variables and function defined in the direct scope of the script tag as global variables (properties of the `window` object in a browser).

It is because the scope of the function inside the `$(document).ready` call is unreachable in the global scope, only by other functions in that scope. If you changed it to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
window.listenFilter = function listenFilter() {
    alert('a');
    return false;
}
});
```

It would work, since you are adding it to the global scope.

`$(document).ready(function(){ })` is the same as doing `(function(){ })()` in the context of this question. Is is a question of scope, not of declaration order. The declaration is being wrapped in a closure which shields it from affecting the global scope.

Comment: One question PitaJ just want to clarify if i have `$(document).ready(function(){ 
(function(){ 
var notglobalbutaccessiblebymanyfunction;

function func0() {
    alert('notglobalbutaccessiblebymanyfunction');
    return false;
}
function func1() {
    alert('notglobalbutaccessiblebymanyfunction');
    return false;
}

})()

});` - Is this good ok to run?

Comment: @Pekka He already have. Though in this case window.listenFilter is used and ready part is ignored for this function as it is in global scope.

Comment: and if it is not global function then it'll not work.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal please check and give suggestion to my question i just want to know if that code will have drawback like slow reaction or maybe not possible

Comment: @Pekka - There is no need for you to add that extra wrapper to your code. It won't fix your problem, only adding it to the global scope will do by setting the `window.listenFilter` property.

Comment: @PitaJ isnt putting a variable into a global scope a bad practice?I i just thought if i put it inside that wrapper then it is not in the global scope but it is with in the scope of the 2 function and i will be able to access it.

Comment: @Pekka - yes, it is. In fact, you should not be using `onclick` attributes at all, but rather programmatically refistering event handlers with the `addEventHandler` DOM method (look it up)

Comment: Yes. It work!. When i study jquery, my brother say $(document).ready(function(){ }) will make the function is defined after the document is loaded. So it's a reason i can't understand clealy.

Comment: @Pekka it isn't because it's defined after the DOM is loaded, that would be fine as long as you didn't click the alert before that event. It's because the function is not being automatically added to the global scope because it is wrapped in another function. So it in that function's scope instead of the global scope.

Comment: @PitaJ yes actually its just a sample so if i do it more precisely it will be like this. If this is the case then everything is ok. I assume.
`$(document).ready(function() {
    (function() {
        var notglobalbutaccessiblebymanyfunction;

        $('#btn0').click( function() {
            alert('notglobalbutaccessiblebymanyfunction');
        });

        $('#btn1').click( function() {
            alert('notglobalbutaccessiblebymanyfunction');
        });
    })()
});`

Answer (score 1):

In the first situation

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function listenFilter() {
        alert('a');
        return false;
    }
});
```

You are saying define the function after the DOM is loaded. So at the time the bellow `anchor` is created, the function `listenFilter` is not defined.

```
< a onclick="listenFilter()" ></a>
```

But in second it will be defined when the `anchor` is loaded because it's defined while parsing `js`.

Comment: Oh Yes. I'm understand it. Thanks @Mritunjay

Comment: @Thunder.Sivler - This answer is wrong. It is not because it is defined after the content is loaded, see my answer below. It's because the closure shields it from the global scope.

Comment: @PitaJ This answer is not wrong. And also your answer is good though.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal - Yes it is. `$(document).ready(function(){  })` is the same as doing `(function(){  })()` in the context of this question. Is is a question of scope, not of declaration order.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal - I did not misread the answer. It says that he's defining it after the DOM is loaded, as if it somehow causes his problem. The declaration order does not matter for `onclick` attributes, as they **always** call the global scope.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal - "You are saying define the function after the DOM is loaded"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89219/discussion-between-bhojendra-nepal-and-pitaj).

Answer (score 0):

remove this `$(document).ready(function () {`

```
<script>
    function listenFilter() {
        alert('a');
        return false;
    }

</script>
```

[JavaScript Functions](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp)

**JavaScript Function Syntax**

1. A JavaScript **function is defined with the function keyword, followed
   by a name**, followed by `parentheses ()`.
2. Function **names can contain letters, digits, underscores, and dollar
   signs** (same rules as variables).
3. The parentheses may include parameter names **separated by commas**:
   (parameter1,  parameter2, ...)
4. The code to be executed, by the **function**, is **placed inside curly
   brackets: {}**